# React native async storage error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

Anyone familiar with this error when migrating over to Androidx ? The error points to the @react-native-community/async-storage.

`error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist`

I'm running on react-native 0.60.5 and @react-native-community-async-storage 1.6.1

Below is the error message when I run `./gradlew build --stacktrace`

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably a version mismatch between the async package and react-native, but I fixed the error by downgrading to react-native 0.59.9. I don't need to upgrade to AndroidX at this time.